# C++で、クラスをデリゲートにする記述方法

Tags: c++

拡張子mmのファイルで、iAdを実装し、チラシを画面下に表示させるところまでは成功したのですが、iAdの実装で、アプリの審査にも関わるbannerViewDidLoadAdとdidFailToReceiveAdWithErrorを実装するために、クラスをデリゲートにしたいと思っていますが、

class Delegate MainScene :publiccocos2d::Layer{

この書き方でエラーが出ます。

それと思わしき場所全てにDelegateを書いたのですが、全てエラーに…。

書き方が悪いのか、それとも内容に問題があるのかわかりません。
他のクラスに依存しているクラスだとデリゲートにできないとネットでみたのですが、他のクラスからメソッドを使用したり関数を使用していることはありません。

C++でクラスをデリゲートにするには、どのように書いたらいいのでしょうか。

Comment: そうなんですか、ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iAdはObjective-Cのライブラリですので、デリゲートに指定できるのはObjective-Cのクラスだけです。C++にはDelegateというキーワードは存在しませんし、C++のクラスをデリゲートに指定することはできません。